# How to transefer arrays to outside functions?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm writing a programme in C that is to make some matrix calculations. However I'm having a problem with transferring two arrays(my matrixs) to the outside function which will add them.

Here is my method of creating dynamic matrix:

```
        int w1, k1;//lines and columns for matrix1
    int* m1;//a pointer for matrix1
    int w2, k2;//lines and columns for matrix2
    int* m2;//a pointer for matrix2

    printf("type the number of lines and columns for matrix1: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &w1, &k1);
    m1 = (int*)malloc(w1 * k1 * sizeof(int));

    printf("type the number of lines and columns for matrix1: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &w2, &k2);
    m2 = (int*)malloc(w2 * k2 * sizeof(int));

    //fulfillement of both arrays

    //matrix1
    int i, j;//for matrix1
    for (i = 0; i < w1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < k1; j++)
        {
            printf("type the values for cell ( %d,%d ): ", i,j);
            scanf("%d", &m1[i*w1 + j]);
        }
    }

    //matrix2
    int m, n;//for matrix2
    for (m = 0; m < w2; m++)
    {
        for (n = 0; n < k2; n++)
        {
            printf("type the values for cell ( %d,%d ): ", m, n);
            scanf("%d", &m2[m * w2 + n]);
        }
    }

    sum(&m1, &m2);
```

Right now I'm trying to transfer both fulfilled arrays to the outside function that will add them. This "sum(&m1,&m2);"... I just don't know how to transfer these arrays to the outside function, and create inside this function an array of the same dimension as given by the user so I can add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know how to pass wanted arguments to a function, you need to know what the function prototype is.

A function's prototype is something like this "return type" "function name" "function arguments".

A function takes arguments and can return a value (if wanted).

For example:

`int  sum_two_ints(int num1, int num2)` is the prototype of a function that takes 2 integers (num1 and num2).

and also returns an integer which is the sum of `num1` and `num2` (hence the "int" before the function name).
To write a function, you need to know what your function's job is and what kind of data it needs to do its job.
In your case, you need a function that will take two matrices and will produce a matrix which is the sum of the two matrices you gave.

Now, what does your function "sum" needs? It needs the two matrices (m1 and m2) which are of the type "int *".
It also needs the dimensions of these two matrices (adding two matrices requiers that they be of the same dimensions).
What does your function return? It will return a new matrix which is the sum of the two matrices you provided.

With these informations in mind, your function will have the following prototype:
`int *sum(int *m1, int *m2, int w, int k)`
The next step will be to write the function body (how it will do its job)
in pseudo-code

```
create a new matrix of the dimensions w * k. (let's call it res)
iterate through all rows and columns of the res matrix and assign its value to be the following:
res[row][col] = m1[row][col] + m2[row][col].
return the resulting matrix as the function's return value.
```

Last step, how to call your function sum from your main function, that's the easiest part.
It takes two arguments of the type "int *" , these are your m1 and m2.
It also takes the width and height of these matrices (w1 and k1 or w2 and k2).
It returns another "int *" variable as the result, so you need to stock it somewhere.
I added the code that implements these information with some comments.
Please read more on how pointers and functions work.
Last note, any call to malloc needs to be met with call to free in the right place, otherwise your program will leak memory.

Cheers

```
int *sum(int *m1, int *m2, int w, int k)
{
int *res;

// resulting matrix will have the same dimensions as m1 and m2.
res = malloc(w * k * sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0 ; i < w; i++)
{
    // Iterate throught the elements of res,
    // the same way you iterated through m1 and m2 to assign their values.
    // Only res[i][j] = m1[i][j] + m2[i][j].
    for(int j = 0 ; j < k ; j++)
    {
        res[i * w + j] = m1[i * w + j] + m2[i * w + j];
    }
}
return (res);
}

int main()
{

int w1, k1;
int* m1;
int w2, k2;
int* m2;

printf("type the number of lines and columns for matrix1: ");
scanf("%d %d", &w1, &k1);
m1 = (int*)malloc(w1 * k1 * sizeof(int));

printf("type the number of lines and columns for matrix1: ");
scanf("%d %d", &w2, &k2);
m2 = (int*)malloc(w2 * k2 * sizeof(int));

// You might want to check that the given arrays have the same dimensions before
// continuing, as adding 2 matrices requiere both matrices to have the same dimensions.
if (w1 != w2 || k1 != k2)
{
    printf("Error, the two matrices don't have the same dimensions\n");
    free(m1);
    free(m2);
    return (0);
}

int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < w1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < k1; j++)
    {
        printf("type the values for cell ( %d,%d ): ", i,j);
        scanf("%d", &m1[i*w1 + j]);
    }
}

int m, n;
for (m = 0; m < w2; m++)
{
    for (n = 0; n < k2; n++)
    {
        printf("type the values for cell ( %d,%d ): ", m, n);
        scanf("%d", &m2[m * w2 + n]);
    }
}
// This will hold the matrix returned as a result of the function sum
int *res;

res = sum(m1, m2, w1, k1);
for (i = 0; i < w1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < k1; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", res[i * w1 + j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
// don't forget to free the space you allocated when you are done with it.
free(m1);
free(m2);
free(res);
return (0);
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to add more information about your answer in text, and point out the problems and the mistakes in the text and not in the code itself :)

Comment: @Reznik, thank you, I edited the answer to have more information

Comment: I'm trying to finish this code using your method given above. However the compiler warns me that:"you cannot assign "void *" values ​​to units of type "int *" ", what should I do with it??

Comment: @szymill00 , can you tell to which line of code the compiler is referring to? i don't see any void * anywhere in the code i provided, and when i compile it i don't get any warning. are you sure you didn't put a "void *" instead of a "int *" somewhere?